# чистка проекта в линукс. configure automake

Tags: c++, linux, c, configure

Не знаю как назвать тему вопроса. В anjuta создаю проект на gtk. В каталоге проекта создаётся файлы. Они находятся в первозданном виде. Это autogen.sh Makefile.am Makefile.in. Но после сборки проекта, появляются файлы configure и каталог autom4te.cache. Что с ними делать. Пробывал `make dist clean`, но толку нет. Как перевести этот каталог в первозданный вид?

Comment: Зачем в 2019 году использовать autotools? Какая система контроля версий используется?

Comment: [dist, clean и distclean](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Standard-Targets.html) — это три совершенно разные цели. вам требуется третья (а не первые две последовательно, как вы написали в вопросе)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin а autom4te.cache не нужен? Он не удаляется. И если configure не делать, то то что оставил после себя autogen.sh это конечно плохо. configure остался, но наверное так лучше. Как сделать чтобы configure тоже был удалён. Я просто не помню какие файлы должны остаться.

Comment: @VTT система контроля версий не используется. В autotools можно параметры определить, какие включить в программу. Да к тому же в anjuta используется autotools, а я пользуюсь anjuta. Она предоставляет удобство при создании собственного виджета на gtk.

Comment: @VTT да и что для вас autotools устарел? Вон ffmpeg до сих пор его используют. Правда там configure вроде кастомный.

Comment: Используйте систему контроля версий. Это облегчит жизнь даже если разработчик и пользователь только вы сами.